# Can someone help me to understand this for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, operators

Hello i'm new learner at java, the tutor on Udemy gave us this method but he didn't explain it, i found it hard to understand, and i tried to execute it, but still the same thing.
PS : sorry for my English i'm Arabian.
**This is the method:**

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

    if(n == 1) {
        return false;
    }

        for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++) {
            if(n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

    return true;


}
```

Comment: I suggest you try running this code in your debugger as it will allow you to see what each line of code does as it does it. This is a very useful tool built into your IDE which you will use many, many, many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `isPrime(int n)` takes an integer `n` and checks whether it is prime or not.

First it checks whether `n` is equal to 1. If it is the method returns false, because 1 is not prime.

Afterwards it loops through all the numbers between `2` and `n/2`, and checks if `n` is divisible by that number. If it is, the method returns false because then it is not prime.

The reason why it does not check every number from `2` til `n` is because it would be redundant. The number `n` can never be expressed as a product of a whole number and a number that is bigger than `n/2`, except `n` but then it would not be a prime number.

Answer (score 2):

The code loops through all numbers from `2` to `n/2` and checks if n is divisible by that number. If it is divisible by any of these numbers the function returns `false` as n has a divisor. If we have found no divisor from `2` to `n/2` the number is prime. A better approach would be to loop to the square root of n.